# how to read form data in spring?

Tags: spring-mvc

Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute

this is my index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form:form action="loginform" method="post">
    <form:input type="text" path="name" id="userName" />
    <form:input type="password" path="pass" id="password" />
    <form:button value="submit"></form:button>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my Bean

```
package com.ews.usman.controller;

public class loginBean {

private String name;
private String pass;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPass() {
    return pass;
}
public void setPass(String pass) {
    this.pass = pass;
}

}
```

this is my Controller

```
package com.ews.usman.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
public class LoginFormController {

@RequestMapping(value="/loginform", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView formReader(@ModelAttribute("loginBean") loginBean
loginbean, BindingResult result){
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("name", loginbean.getName());
    model.addObject("pass", loginbean.getPass());
    model.setViewName("result");
    return model;
}


}
```

this is my Servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing
infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up
static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.ews.usman" />

<bean name="/loginform"
class="com.ews.usman.controller.LoginFormController"></bean>

</beans:beans>
```

this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and
Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-
class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-
class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-
value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>`
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a *modelAttribute* with a proper name to your form, otherwise the form backing bean name will default to 'command' hence you get your error

```
<form:form action="loginform" modelAttribute="loginBean" method="post">
```